# colors = Color.query.all()

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Hi I am trying to follow this tutorial to learn how to get pagination in my flask project.

https://betterprogramming.pub/simple-flask-pagination-example-4190b12c2e2e

I am having problems with the following line

"colors = Color.query.all()"

Where does "Color" come from ?

In all the tutorials I have read this form of variable appears but no explanation where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

The Color class is a database model that was implemented with [flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/). The class can be used to add, remove and query entries in a database table.

The definition of the model is as follows and contains three columns. The ID as a unique key for identification, the name of the color and a date when the database entry was added.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

# ...

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Color(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
        nullable=False, unique=False, index=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)

# ...
```

To use the database you have to create the necessary tables either via the flask shell or within your code like here.

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

The flask-SQLAlchemy introductory [example](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) and the SQLAlchemy [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/) explain more.

I also recommend this [series of articles](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) as a good tutorial for flask.

Have fun.